# R: Average nearby elements in a vector

Tags: r, vector, grouping

I have many vectors such as this: `c(28,  30,  50,  55,  99, 102)` and I would like to obtain a new vector where elements differing less than 10 from one to another are averaged. In this case, I would like to obtain `c(29, 52.5, 100.5)`.

Comment: Do you care about the order ot not? For example, for a vector like this `c(10, 50, 80, 22, 89, 98, 102)` do you want to treat `10` and `22` as two groups or a single group?

Comment: Dear David, my vectors are already ordered... so 10 and 22 should belong to the same group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way

```
vec <- c(28, 30, 50, 55, 99, 102)
indx <- cumsum(c(0, diff(vec)) > 10)
tapply(vec, indx, mean)
#    0     1     2 
# 29.0  52.5 100.5
```

Comment: I have to run, but can you check whether `c(10, 50, 80, 22, 89, 98, 102)`  this works. (or may be I am wrong).

Comment: @akrun see response from the OP

Comment: Your solution is right, anyway.  Mine won't work in certain cases.